# Unit Testing Actual Procedure

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm involved in a C project which did not have unit testing during its development. What my superior is asking me is to do bug fixes and create unit tests for the parts which involved modifications. This is also my first time creating tests since I'm also a newbie so he gave me a document describing the procedures.

He said to check the flow control in the function I modified (say func()) and gave a sample test case which goes something like this:

```
func(int a)  
{  
 if(a == 5)
    ifblock();
 else
    elseblock();
}
```

1.) input:5, check if flow will go to ifblock()
2.) input:6, check if flow will go to elseblock()

Now the real function involves a more complex condition check compared to the sample but this only for discussion.

My problem is that I do not see the benefit of doing this particular kind of test case (I'm not against unit testing to clarify. just this particular example) so I told him my reasons:
1.) This kind of checking does not prove the function's correctness
2.) I have to create another test case if the code changed even if input and output of function is still the same.
3.) Waste of time especially when I have maybe a hundred similar test cases
4.) From what I read, it seems a function is what is referred to as a unit so no point going line by line (I can see the point in assembly language though)

What  I plan to do is to have a set of inputs that will target the modification/specification and check output which simpler and reusable.

He doesn't budge with his instructions but cant explain to me the importance of this one.
So if anyone could enlighten me with this since I'm still a newbie and maybe just can't see its value as of this moment.

Comment: Google "why unit testing is important" or something. You're asking us to write blog posts and/or textbooks on the subject here which is inappropriate for SO.

Comment: yup,did that but no site gave a definite answer so last option is to post here

Comment: That's *exactly* why you shouldn't post it here. If it's so broad and opinion-based that many writers can't give you a solitary definite answer, then it does not have a solitary definite answer, and is therefore off topic.

Comment: IOW - you're assuming that the true master of unit tests has been lurking on SO all along and will write the trump post in response to this question, ending the need for anyone else to write about it ever again. This is not plausible.

Comment: Ok I get your point. So I'm thinking I have to read some books and decide on my own is what you are saying? I'm doing the reading but it will take a long time. Anyway, I'll delete this post after 20 mins.

Comment: If you catch a defect in your software - before any body else - you save embarrassment and it is cheap to fix

Comment: an insignificant remark: there's no shortcut to professionalism

Comment: @Dmitry  Not insignificant.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests are the safety net for further modifications to the code. Some code is easier to test, some is more complicated. In your case of if/else could be interpreted as the definition of the [behavior](http://cukes.info/) of the system that you have on your hands, which is it's specification.

You can write your unit test as such (specification), and maybe it will help you in understanding the value of such a test. It might seem that you're merely repeating the code that you're trying to test, but if you strive for simplicity and completeness of your tests, you might later be able to throw the implementation, and create a newer, cleaner one.

As you're intending to modify code, that is exactly what your unit tests will be for - defining what was there before, and specifying what is new and what has changed, as you go about changing what's already there.

It is not possible to generalize and give a one-sentence answer to your discourse, and it all depends on too many things - on the desired fate of the software in question, on your willingness to become better at what you do, on the actual state of software you're dealing with, etc.

There are some books that might help you and your boss have solid reasons for writing tests:

- "Clean Code" & "Clean Coder" by Robert C. Martin
- "Refactoring" by Martin Fowler, Kent Beck, John Brant and William Opdyke
- "Test Driven Development: By Example" by Kent Beck
- "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers

As for the bullet points:

1. It depends on how one writes the test, and what is considered as "correct". If you define as correct a list of inputs and valid outputs (or ranges thereof), then a test that checks exactly that is the "proof"
2. Why? You'll have to create another test case if you change or extend the function's behavior. If you're not changing it, you shouldn't have to touch the test
3. Consider data driven testing, in case you're merely checking ranges of inputs and outputs
4. What do you mean by going line by line? There's a concept of "coverage", meaning that your test exercises a certain portion of your code (statement by statement is a better view than line by line, perhaps). You might want to increase that metric when you write your test

P.S.

> What I plan to do is to have a set of inputs that will target the
>   modification/specification and check output which simpler and
>   reusable.

that is data-driven testing

The reason for checking the code line by line may have a very pragmatic reason. You might think of the function as a simple black box with inputs and outputs. You may then create a table for your data-driven test, and run the test, measuring the code coverage. You might even get surprised, that a lot of code is not being hit at all. It might be wise to assume that all lines of code initially had some reason, otherwise they wouldn't be in that function. Trying to discover the reasons behind each line of code (explorative unit testing) can create an even more solid safety net for further refactoring and extensions, at the same time, increasing your understanding of the code.

P.P.S.
Another consequence of trying to write the tests may be that you find the code to be obscure, outdated and not very well-written. In that case, you might want to throw the implementation all together, relying only on the specification tests for a complete rewrite.

Comment: Good answer.  A unit test for the Question code might include unexpected integer values; such as 0, -1 & INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is very much necessary after development. And a developer best knows about his code's expected outcome.
You have to prepare test cases based on the functionality (Positive outcome) and Validations in code.

So, the testcase categories will be as:

1. Functionality Test Cases - Have List of positive Input and expected output as example
2. All kinds of validation for negative input whether your code is able to handle the validation or able to avoid any unexpected output.

Even if you change code, the test cases will remain same in this case.

Comment: I disagree - It should be a part of development

Comment: I agree with you Ed. It is part of development. But it depends how the developer does that whether during module based development or after finishing development. And i hope if i write unit test cases before starting development, i will test my code based on test cases only after finishing the code.